# Style.css mysteriously turned into one line

Tags: css, sublimetext2, minify

I'm developing a site using the Divi WP theme, using a child theme. I had a style.css that I was working with in Sublime Text 2.

After making a change and reloading the css, it all got turned into one line, instead of being multiple lines down the page. I can unminify using a tool online and a bunch of manual editing, but I'm afraid this will happen again.

There are no "automatic" minifying plugins in use or any other thing that should cause this.

I've never had this happen before.

What can I do to keep it from happening again?

Thanks.